# Use ValueConverter with Source and Path in Winrt Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have TextBox that have TwoWay binding with settings class. I want to force text replace (comma to dot) using Value Converter with name DecimaFormatConveters.
Namely, I use TextBox for input decimal number but if I have comma in number then number that goes to appSettings class is convert from i.e. 12,125 to 12. I lose decimal places. I want with Value Converter to replace comma with dot and then I would not have problem because two way binding send real decimal number 12.125 to my appSettings class.

If I catch value in appSettings class, value is without decimal places 12 so I would like to use value converter for conversion.
My code with ValueConverter doesn't work:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb_name" InputScope="Number" 
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings},Path=property_name, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DecimaFormatConveters}}" />
```

Error code: Error 13 Specified cast is not valid

Any suggestions?

Comment: show as the converter code and the usage in xaml

Comment: You'd need to take a look at your data type usage. It sounds like you are using integer instead of double or decimal. Also since this value is coming in as a string, be careful how you do your conversations. It would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Thanks. The ValueConverter had a problem.